# How do you write a vbs variable to a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

here is the code:

---

---

---

```
Const MY_COMPUTER = &H11&
Const WINDOW_HANDLE = 0
Const OPTIONS = 0

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(MY_COMPUTER)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
strPath = objFolderItem.Path

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder _
(WINDOW_HANDLE, "Select a folder:", OPTIONS, strPath) 

If objFolder Is Nothing Then
Wscript.Quit
End If

Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
objPath = objFolderItem.Path

wscript.Echo objPath
```

---

---

---

Now this part works, now i need to write "objPath" to a "file.bat".
In batch files it would simply be "echo objPath>>hello.txt" but this does not seem to work with vbs!

Can anyone help me?

The batch file calls the VBS file to prompt the user to select a directory he/she wants to copy and then the directory he wants to copy to. Then the batch file automatically copies the first location selected to the second location every time the computer boots! Like a backup system! but only for one specific folder! Thanks for the help!

Comment: How are the files intended to be run? Modified batch from your vbs, your vbs and modified batch from other process, modified batch is calling your vbs, ...?

Comment: Well basically the batch file calls the vbs to prompt the user to select a directory he want to copy and then the directory he wants to copy to. Then the file automatically copies the file to the second location every time the computer boots! Like a backup system! but only for one specific folder! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a browseforfolder routine I wrote that does what you want. You can use it as is or just as a reference for your code. It returns a 0 if a valid path is selected or a 1 if you click the cancel button.

Everything that follows goes into a batch file.

```
@Echo off
setlocal
Call :BrowseFolder "Choose Source folder" "C:\scripts\batch\" r
echo %r%
echo %errorlevel%
Call :BrowseFolder "Choose Destination folder" "C:\scripts\" r
echo %r%
echo %errorlevel%
cmd /k
Goto :EOF


:BrowseFolder
setlocal
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
>%vbs% echo set sh=wscript.CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
>>%vbs% echo set f=sh.BrowseForFolder(0,%1,0,%2) 
>>%vbs% echo if typename(f)="Nothing" Then 
>>%vbs% echo   wscript.echo "Dialog Cancelled" 
>>%vbs% echo   wscript.Quit(1) 
>>%vbs% echo end if 
>>%vbs% echo set fs=f.Items():set fi=fs.Item() 
>>%vbs% echo p=fi.Path:wscript.echo p
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('cscript //nologo %vbs%') do set result=%%a
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
if "%result%" EQU "Dialog Cancelled" (set a=1) else set a=0
endlocal & set %3=%result% & exit /b %a%
```

Version 1 - Writes out a .cmd file and calls it to set environment variable.

```
:BrowseFolder
set Result=
set vbs="%temp%\_.vbs"
set cmd="%temp%\_.cmd"
for %%f in (%vbs% %cmd%) do if exist %%f del %%f
for %%g in ("vbs cmd") do if defined %%g set %%g=
>%vbs% echo set shell=WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
>>%vbs% echo set f=shell.BrowseForFolder(0,%1,0,%2) 
>>%vbs% echo if typename(f)="Nothing" Then  
>>%vbs% echo wscript.echo "set Result=Dialog Cancelled" 
>>%vbs% echo WScript.Quit(1)
>>%vbs% echo end if 
>>%vbs% echo set fs=f.Items():set fi=fs.Item() 
>>%vbs% echo p=fi.Path:wscript.echo "set Result=" ^& p
cscript //nologo %vbs% > %cmd%
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%cmd%) do %%a
for %%f in (%vbs% %cmd%) do if exist %%f del /f /q %%f
for %%g in ("vbs cmd") do if defined %%g set %%g=
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thanks man, the thing is i want to write a batch file that asks the user what directory he wants copied, then with backs up that directory to the second location he selected every time the computer boots. So the batch file is copied to the windows start up folder. That's why i'm stuck. I don't know how to save the directory he/she selected to another file! Thanks for the help!

Comment: David already told you how to output the result to another file. Did you try it? What happened?  I posted another earlier version of my routine that writes to a .cmd file and calls it to set a global variable for the location.